# Better way to store mongo collections details as Java constants

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

```
public class MongoDBConstants {

    // Define the collection names
    public static final String USER_COLLECTION = "users";
    public static final String PRODUCT_COLLECTION = "products";
    
    // Define the fields for the "users" collection
    public static final String USER_ID = "userId";
    public static final String USER_NAME = "userName";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL = "userEmail";
    public static final String USER_AGE = "userAge";
    public static final String USER_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String USER_ADDRESS_STREET = "street";
    public static final String USER_ADDRESS_CITY = "city";
    public static final String USER_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    public static final String USER_CONTACTS_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String USER_CONTACTS_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String USER_ORDERS = "orders";
    public static final String USER_ORDERS_ORDER_ID = "orderId";
    public static final String USER_ORDERS_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String USER_ORDERS_PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";
    public static final String USER_ORDERS_PRODUCT_PRICE = "productPrice";
    
    // Define the fields for the "products" collection
    public static final String PRODUCT_ID = "productId";
    public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";
    public static final String PRODUCT_PRICE = "productPrice";
    public static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY = "productCategory";
    public static final String PRODUCT_DETAILS = "productDetails";
    public static final String PRODUCT_DETAILS_MANUFACTURER = "manufacturer";
    public static final String PRODUCT_DETAILS_DESCRIPTION = "description";

}
```

Hi, I’m working on the Springboot boot project with *MongoDb* connection. 
Currently storing mongodb collection details like collection and field names are storing as constants in a *Java* file. Just wondering is there a better way to store these constants other than as *Java* constants which give developers better understanding of the mongo collection structure and dynamic usage in queries like elementary where there is no need of referring a field from its topmost parent level field ?